# A property of the Radon-Nikodym derivative

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

If $\nu \ll \mu$, with $\mu$ a positive measure and $\nu$ a signed measure, both $\sigma$-finite, then we let $\frac{d\nu}{d\mu}$ denote the Radon-Nikodym derivative, so that
$$\int_E d\nu = \int_E \frac{d\nu}{d\mu}d\mu$$
If $\nu \ll \mu$, $f$ is a non-negative measurable function, and we further have that $\int_X f(x) d\nu^- d(x) < \infty$, then prove that
$$\int_X f(x) d\nu(x) = \int_X f(x) \frac{d\nu}{d\mu}(x) d\mu(x)$$
I have done this exercise in the case when $g \in L^1(\nu)$ and when $f$ is just assumed to be non-negative and measurable. However, it is not clear to me how to do it in this case. Obviously, since I proved this for the case when $f$ is a non-negative measurable function this result follows. However, how does this extra assumption make the problem simpler?

Comment: what is $\nu^{-}$?

Comment: It is the negative variation, given by $\nu^- = \frac{1}{2}(|\nu|-\nu)$, where $|\nu|$ is the total variation.

Comment: What is $g$? You have to be careful when $\nu$ is a signed measure because $\int f\,d\nu = \int f \,d\nu^+ - \int f \,d\nu^-$ does not make sense for all $f \geq 0$. It only makes when one of $\int f \,d\nu^+$ or $\int f \,d\nu^-$ is finite.